# Regular expression for detecting round or square brackets

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find aiport codes given a string like `(JFK)` or `[FRA]` using a regular expression.

I'm don't have to make sure if the mentioned airport code is correct. The braces can pretty much contain any three capital letters.

Here's my current solution which does work for round brackets but not for square brackets:

```
[((\[]([A-Z]{{3}})[))\]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your regular expression seems like it is try to match too much, try this one:

```
^[(\[][A-Z]{3}[)\]]$
```

`^`      matches the beginning of the line (something you may or may not need)

`[(\[]`  is a character class that matches `(` or `[`

`[A-Z]{3}` matches three capitol letters

`[)\]]` is a character class that matches `)` or `]`

`$`     matches the end of the line (something you may or may not need)

[Click here to see the test results](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5E%5B%28%5C%5B%5D%5BA-Z%5D%7B3%7D%5B%29%5C%5D%5D%24&input=%28FRA%29)

Note that `[` and `]` are special characters in regular expressions and I had to escape them with a `\` to indicate I wanted a literal character.

Hope this helps

Comment: The regex sets I know do not support escaping, they don't support meta characters, but match the characters itself. The question is how to include either of `]`, and `^` in a set, and the answer is put at the right place! e.g. `^`, `[]^]`, `[^]^]`

Comment: That would match `(FRA]`, too!

Answer (score 3):

if you want to (1) match the letters in a single matching group and (2) only match parens *or* brackets (not one of each) then it's quite hard.  one solution is:

```
.([A-Z]{3}).((?<=\(...\))|(?<=\[...\]))
```

where the first part matches the letters and the trailing mess checks the brackets/parens.

see http://fiddle.re/u19v - this matches `[ABC]` and `(DEF)`, but not `(PQR]` (which the "correct" answer does).

if you want the parens in the match, move the capturing parens outside the `.`:

```
(.[A-Z]{3}.)((?<=\(...\))|(?<=\[...\]))
```

the underlying problem here is that regexes are not powerful enough to match pairs of values (like parens or brackets) in the way you would like.  so each different kind of pair has to be handled separately.

Comment: There are people who say that the question is not how far can we go with regexes (which are in practice irregular regexes today), but how for **should** we go...

Answer (score 0):

Easy to understand, more dialect agnostic and correct:

```
^([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z])\|\[[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\]$
```

You might have to change the escaping of parens and pipes depending on your regex dialect.

Comment: this will only place the letters in parens (not square brackets) in the matching group.  if you include the second pattern in parens too then you can retrieve either, but they will be in different groups, i think.  hence my solution...

Comment: @andrewcooke: That's no matching group, but literally parens. (Quoting myself: `You might have to change the escaping of parens and pipes depending on your regex dialect.`)

Comment: regular expressions use parens for grouping, even if they don't capture (parens are included in the "basic concepts" section of the wikipedia article, for example).  so you always need to escape them if you want to use them as literals (unless you're inside a character set - inside square brackets - where the rules change).  do you have an example of a regular expression implementation for which your expression would work?

Comment: Your first sentence makes not sense to me (I can't see the logic). As to the question, yes, sure, POSIX Basic Regular Expressions (as used in `grep` and probably many other tools by default).

Comment: hmmm.  ok, it seems that grep in linux, at least, extends BRE with alternation (| is not in the posix standard for BRE).  i actually didn't know BRE was a regular expression (if you see what i mean) - i thought there was nothing between globbing and ERE.

Comment: True, alternation isn't actually part of BRE, I didn't know. But I would not say that BRE is "between" globbing and ERE. BRE is just on of the many regex flavors around (and the one I'm accustomed to as a heavy shell user).