# Regex to detect the first set of square brackets with anything inside them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

So I suck at RegExes. Still.

I'm looping over some HTML-inputs with jQuery, and, in their name attributes, I would like to replace **only** the first set of the square brackets with "anything" inside them.

I've got these HTML-inputs:

```
<fieldset id="set">
    <input type="text" name="shift[305][sub_amount]" value="Snoopy" />
    <input type="text" name="shift[405][price]" value="12" />
    <input type="text" name="cost[insert_1392222118][amount]" value="Hoof" />
</fieldset>
```

And my goal is this

```
<fieldset id="set">
    <input type="text" name="shift[replaced][sub_amount]" value="Snoopy" />
    <input type="text" name="shift[replaced][price]" value="12" />
    <input type="text" name="cost[replaced][amount]" value="Hoof" />
</fieldset>
```

So I'm looping over them like so:

```
$('#set').find(":input").attr("name", function(index, element) {
    return element.replace(/\[[0-9]+\]/, function(match) {
        return '[replaced]';
    })
});
```

But my regex only fixes the square brackets with numeric data in them.

JSFiddle-example that only solves it when the square brackets only contain numeric data:
http://jsfiddle.net/XLnAC/

**Who can tell me which RegEx to use to target the first instance of square brackets with anything inside them?**

I've found similar questions, but no details on how to only find the first instances.
[Regular expression for detecting round or square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310472/regular-expression-for-detecting-round-or-square-brackets)

Comment: Can `anything` be nothing?

Comment: No, in my case, between the brackets there would always be or a number, or a string. Good point though!

Comment: There is always that possibility of nested brackets. JS certainly won't do balanced text constructs. Also, can `anything` be nothing?

Comment: Nested brackets wont be the case in my situation. Only integers or strings. Good remark though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this one :

```
/\[[^\]]+\]/
```

You also don't need to use a function here :

```
return element.replace(/\[[^\]]+\]/, '[replaced]')
```

Comment: Hi @FritsvanCampen, I'm afraid you're right. Check the edited JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/XLnAC/

Comment: If you remove the `g` it works .. which might be just as well.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Yes, I initially overlooked that part of the question. I fixed it.

Comment: Yep, this works. Thank you, @dystroy. I will be validating your answer as soon as SO allows this.